# Code dropdown to display values from mysql table

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox, xampp

how do I code a combo box in vb2010 so it displays values from a field in a table from mysql? I can't seem to find anything online (probably because I don't know how to phrase the search).

connection string: `("Server=localhost;database=ba-solutions;user id=root;password=")`

```
   Private Sub cbxCompanyName_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbxCompanyName.SelectedIndexChanged
    Try
        'we open Connection
        connection.Open()

        With mycommand
            .CommandText = "SELECT `companyname` from client_details;"
        End With
        'declare dt as new datatable
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        With cbxCompanyName


            myadapter.SelectCommand = mycommand
            'it fills the da values into dt
            myadapter.Fill(dt)
            'dt provides the data surce of combobox
            .DataSource = dt
            'specify the what to display
            .DisplayMember = "companyname"
            'and the value
            .ValueMember = "companyname"
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What is your problem? Retrieving data from DB? Creating a ComboBox? Displaying data?

Comment: So I make a combobox in a form and the results of the combo box has to be data that is in mysql database?

Comment: Please append the code you've done so far.

Comment: I've edited the code I think I should be using, but I don't know how to link the code to the table and combobox?

Comment: You've created an infinite recursion! Changing the source of the combobox will fire the selectedindexchanged event. Picture this: `DataSourceChanged > SelectedIndexChanged > DataSourceChanged > SelectedIndexChanged > DataSourceChanged ...`